# Crontab run every 3 months starting from July

Tags: cron, cron-task

When i tried to make my crontab to run a job every 3 months starting from July i use this expression `15 11 11 7/3 *`
I then get this error.
`crontab: installing new crontab "/tmp/crontab.vM7zCi":3: bad month errors in crontab file, can't install.`
Ive tried reading online how to do this and this should be right?

Comment: how many times? once every 3 months? any particular time?

Comment: Yup once every 3 months, at 11.15 on the 11th of that month

Answer (score 1):

If you used `*/3`, your job would run in every month that's a multiple of 3 (months 3, 6, 9, and 12).

Normally you could specify what you want by combining a range followed by `/3`, e.g. `1-12/3` -- but ranges are not allowed for the month or day-of-week fields. Quoting the `crontab(5)` man page for Vixie cron, the most common implementation:

> Names can also be used for the "month" and "day of week" fields.
> Use the first three letters of the particular day or month (case
> doesn't  matter).  Ranges or lists of names are not allowed.

But numeric lists are allowed.  Since there are only 4 months you want to specify, just list them all:

```
15 11 11 1,4,7,10 * your-command-here
```